# How to prepare my own dataset in tensorflow with data in form of images and labels in form of a text file?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to train a convolutional neural network (CNN) in tensor-flow, I have data in terms of 10,000 images in .png format and labels in a text file in .txt format, where each line contains a single label (over all 10,000 lines). How can I prepare my own dataset in tensor-flow and train the network?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine your main concern is the image part. Either convert to jpg and use [decode_jpeg](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/image.html#decode_jpeg), or use [ImageFlow](https://github.com/HamedMP/ImageFlow) to convert to TFRecords.

Comment: I have found on the Internet but i could not find any clear tutorial on working with our own data, there are number of tutorials on publicly available datasets like CIFAR, MNSIT etc. can any one help in this regard?

Comment: Can you clarify what you need help on?  AFAIK the two methods I proposed will get you all the way to tensors already.

Comment: i have around 10,000 png images and their labels are stored in a txt file (with each label separated by new line), can you help me to prepare my dataset for training a CNN.

Comment: I want to train a CNN model like CIFAR-10 with my own dataset.

Comment: For the txt file label, you can just use decode_csv() with one column (assuming you set a non-existent delimiter).  See https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#file-formats for example.

Comment: @Ali have you made your dataset?